# Neo4j client-server API

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, client-server

### What is the way to use Java API in client-server setup of Neo4j?

Do I miss some kind of Java connector ? Only thing I found so far was REST api:http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html, but I have no idea how to use objects like:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;
org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.ConstraintDefinition;
org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.ConstraintType;
```

over REST. I want to avoid constructing cumbersome URLs and parse string responses. I want to migrate from my application from embedded to client-server, but so far it seems to impossible.

Comment: What type of client technology will you be using?  Would this be something like a JSP-based client in which the views are built on the server-side, or would it be more like a JavaScript-based client in which the views are built on the client-side?  If the latter, then you'll need something similar to the REST API, because the client will not have access to the Java API.

Comment: At present, there is no "java connector" like JDBC for neo4j - you have two options, use neo4j as an embedded database (in which case it's not client server) or use the server and its RESTful services (in which case it is client server).  To use those classes, read the tutorial on how to use neo4j as an embedded DB  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html

Comment: I use Vaadin client. It's 100% server side. So far I use embedded, utilizing classes mentioned above. I want to know if I will have to stay with embedded forever, since I use Java api. So far looks so.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a JDBC connector for Neo4j, check out:

http://neo4j.com/developer/java/#_using_neo4j_server_with_jdbc

And:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc#minimum-viable-snippet

```
// Make sure Neo4j Driver is registered
Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");

// Connect
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/");

// Querying
try(Statement stmt = con.createStatement())
{
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("MATCH (n:User) RETURN n.name");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("n.name"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this might be something useful. I don't see any security (no  user, no password), but I'll check it out.  Thought its not Java api, and possibly requires a lot of string parsing...

Answer (score 0):

I think FrobberOfBits answered this one right. Theres no Java API for client-server.